# which is the simplest framework in order to build a Workflow in Java?

Tags: jakarta-ee, workflow, wildfly-10

I am in the beginning of a Java web application project and I have to decide which framework I will use in order to build my Workflow(s).

I am looking for a simple and easy framework, because I need only a few workflows.

I looked up for some frameworks like easyflow, Bonita, jBPM, Activiti.

Which framework would you suggest to use, given that:

1. The web application is not complex and does not need the ultimate framework to build the workflows.
2. The framework should be as simple as possible (not complex), so that it will not be an overkill for the developer.
3. The workflows are based on roles which are defined on a Wildfly server.

I would really want to read your answers and I would appreciate it, if you could describe the reasons you have suggested that framework.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Asking for a framework recommendation is off-topic because they attract opinionated answers.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using jBPM in my workplace for the past 2,5 years and this has been running in production in the last 2 years.

Before I joined to my company, they used to use Activity.

I honestly don't know much the reasons why they want to change it. However, one of the reason is that it is not suitable for the requirements. In addition, jBPM community's response is relatively fast.

I am not a developer so that I just keep modelling the business process. However, you should at least know about java as there is some script that you have to write in Java in order to overcome some complex issues.

The installation now is also stress-free as they have provided docker, and I am in love with this since I used it 6 months ago. With the latest version (6.5) I feel this has been more stable compared to 6.4 or 6.3. It also comes with Kie-Server and Workbenches. Basically, Workbench is web-framework to model the business process while KIE-server is the run time after we deploy a container and it has REST API to communicate with your client side.

In summary, even though my models are relatively complex, I believe it can be suited to your needs which only need few workflows. Hope this helps. Perhaps you need other opinions in regard to other products

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.